# What is the practice of pricing goods at numbers such as 3.95, 69.90, 198 called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for pricing items just below a significant value (e.g. $19,995)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7025/what-is-the-term-for-pricing-items-just-below-a-significant-value-e-g-19-995)

It is common on price tags to use $3.95 instead of $4.00 to make items appear cheaper. Is there a name for this practice?  See also [this closed post on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/are-shoppers-disproportionately-more-likely-to-buy-an-item-if-it-costs-3-95-com) for context.

Comment: what? You want us to tell you that the word for price tags is price tags? Or are you looking for *price*?

Comment: Please don't downvote a question because you don't understand it...

Comment: @MattEllen I believe the question being asked here is "what is the practice of pricing goods at numbers such as .95, .99 called?"

Comment: @Jeremy - poorly asked questions *should* be down voted. That is what down voting is for.

Comment: @Matt Ellen That's a good point. In my opinion, this question was fairly well worded and clear, though.

Comment: @MattEllen http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down "*Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing. Instead of voting down: If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.*"

Comment: @Samthere: I think this was a sever case. I could not figure out what was being asked, and from what I could see there was nothing redeeming about this question. Thus I down voted.

Comment: Thanks editor for clarifying it. But the edited question doesn't cover prices like 69.90, 198.00 that I am also interested in

Comment: @whoabackoff that's great. I'll keep down voting questions I find to be low quality. Y'all can keep up voting them.

Comment: I think it's fair to downvote based on personal opinion, as long as the downvoter genuinely thinks it's  extremely bad

Comment: @LouisRhys I did what I could, but if there is more that you want to add, you should edit your question and add it.  Leaving it in the comments makes it difficult to find.

Comment: I am 99% sure I know the answer to this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around and reading a bit, the only place I saw someone actually use a term for it was [here](http://www.consumerpsychologist.com/food_Price_and_Competition.html), where it is referred to as *odd pricing*.

> **Odd-even Pricing.**  Most supermarkets tend to use the so-called “odd” prices—those ending in .99 or .95—rather than round dollar figures.  Many believe that this practice is intended to make prices seem lower than they are.  For example, $2.99 could be seen as “two dollars plus ‘change’” rather than “almost three dollars.”  Research shows that consumers are slightly more likely to purchase at these odd prices, but the effect is not large.  Odd prices may send a signal that a product is a “bargain.”...

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pricing) on Wikipedia. It uses the terms **psychological pricing** and **price ending**.

> Psychological pricing or price ending is a marketing practice based on the theory that certain prices have a psychological impact. The retail prices are often expressed as "odd prices": a little less than a round number, e.g. $19.99 or £2.98. The theory is this drives demand greater than would be expected if consumers were perfectly rational. Psychological pricing is one cause of price points.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this called “price points” and “price rounding rules” in [retail pricing software](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=retail+pricing+softwarwe&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-gb%3aIE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=BI1OTqGkIYe7hAfZyOXZBg#hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-gb%3aIE-Address&sa=X&ei=BI1OTrieJcWJhQewy7n8Bg&ved=0CF8QvwUoAQ&q=retail+pricing+software&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=743b6f47efdc5785&biw=1298&bih=834).

Comment: In my experience, "price points" refers to the retail price; one might use *odd pricing* as a means of determining a price point for instance.